# ElasticSearch Error while Installing Magneto 2.4 using CLI

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I'm trying to install a fresh Magento 2.4 CE on my local PC.

Here are my configurations:

1. Magento 2.4 CE
2. Apache 2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
3. PHP 7.4.8 (cli)
4. mysql Ver 8.0.21 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
5. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I'm trying to install using CLI with this command:

```bash
    php bin/magento setup:install 
    --backend-frontname="admin" 
    --key="240d2e12f0f04fdd2dfd2a9bd616b1f6" 
    --session-save="files" 
    --db-host="localhost:9200" 
    --db-name="magento24" 
    --db-user="root" 
    --db-password="admin123" 
    --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento24/" 
    --base-url-secure="https://127.0.0.1/magento24/" 
    --admin-user="admin" 
    --admin-password="admin123" 
    --admin-email="admin@admin.com" 
    --admin-firstname="admin" 
    --admin-lastname="khan"
```

I am getting error Here

```
In SearchConfig.php line 81:
                                                                           
  Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Magento documentation, you must install ElasticSearch first before installing Magento.

[Magento Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/elasticsearch.html)

Easiest way to run it in local environment is with Docker.
Here's a guide for that: [Install ElasticSearch with Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html)

Answer (score 1):

You must enable ElasticSearch in Magento 2.4, it's a requirement as you can see in the page [Magento 2.4 technology stack requirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html).

#### The issue is the ElasticSearch missing in your command.

To start the verification, you can run this curl command below to validate your ElasticSearch, you can change the host **elasticsearch** to your host.

```
curl elasticsearch:9200
```

#### Install again

Then you can install it again using this command below.

```
php bin/magento setup:install 
--backend-frontname="admin" 
--key="240d2e12f0f04fdd2dfd2a9bd616b1f6" 
--session-save="files" 
--db-host="localhost:9200" 
--db-name="magento24" 
--db-user="root" 
--db-password="admin123" 
--base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento24/" 
--base-url-secure="https://127.0.0.1/magento24/" 
--admin-user="admin" 
--admin-password="admin123" 
--admin-email="admin@admin.com" 
--admin-firstname="admin" 
--admin-lastname="khan"
--elasticsearch-host=elasticsearch
```

Comment: I did the all above and also install elastic search after that I get a new error in xampp i,e "Current version of RDBMS is not supported. Used Version: 10.1.37-MariaDB. Supported versions: MySQL-8, MySQL-5.7, MariaDB-(10.2-10.4)" now I update the MySQL version also and setup button is still not appearing.

Comment: In this version, there is no setup button, as you already upgrade the MySQL version, you need to run the command via terminal again.

Comment: Which command? Setup command I do that but there are showing errors and waring. I solved many like install elastic search then upgrade MySQL version but still showing error in the console.

Comment: @kantsverma the command in my answer, which error are you having?

Comment: For me, adding --elasticsearch-host=elasticsearch --elasticsearch-port=9200 worked for me in dockr